Quick multiplication of 3-digit mirror numbers?
I am looking for a quick trick to multiply two 3-digit mirror numbers. Using a trinomial expansion, I was able to find out that $$(100a + 10b + c)(100c+10b+a) = 10001ac+1010b(a+c)+100(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$ Which is convenient for low-digit numbers like 231 and 132, but a bit of a headache for numbers like 968 and 869. Is there any way to make this process faster mentally?

I don't think there is any easier way. This is the easiest one for the given topic. If you want to improve your calculation speed you can search for squaring and multiplication tricks that can be applied here I guess. I'm not sure though. Did you have any progress of your own?

Here is my take on this:
First, the trinomial expansion
$$(100a + 10b + c)(100c + 10b + a) = 1001ac + 1010b(a+c) + 100 (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)$$
is correct. Now, define a mirror pair as a pair of numbers $n_1, n_2$ such that the only difference between these numbers is that the first and last digits of these numbers are swapped.
For $n_1 = 100a + 10b + c$, $n_2 = 100c + 10b + a$, notice the following
$$n_1 + n_2 = 101(a+c) + 20b, n_1 - n_2 = 99(a-c)$$
This means that $$\fbox{$1010b(a+c)=10b(n_1+n_2)-200b^2$} \tag{1}$$
Putting $(1)$ back into the trinomial expansion (a.k.a $n_1n_2$), we get
$$\fbox{$n_1n_2=100(a^2-b^2+c^2) + 1001ac + 10b(n_1+n_2)$}$$
Other than this, unless $b$ is related to $a,c$ by subtraction, multiplication, addition, division, polynomials etc., I think the trinomial expansion you gave is the fastest way (followed by the alternative representation I have given).
